# MS Access calling a function

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am writing a programme for membership of a club in Access. Cell 1 will contain a number and cell 2 will contain cell 1 number in roman numerals.

I have a function that will convert the number but am having trouble getting cell 1 value into the function and the answer into cell 2. The start of the function is

```
Public Function RomanNumeral(ByVal aValue As Long) As String
```

and ends with

```
RomanNumeral = strResult
```

I would be very happy if anyone can help

Comment: There are no "cells" in Access. Are you doing this in a table? In a query?

Comment: Sorry about that, they are actually fields in a database and the fields are on a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this would be a calculated field. For this, you use `=myFunction()` as `ControlSource`.

In your case, if the number field has the name `myNumber`, use this for the roman number field:

```
=RomanNumeral([myNumber])
```

**Edit**

If you don't want a calculated field, but a field in the table, create an **AfterUpdate** event procedure for the number field, where you set the second field:

```vb
Private Sub myNumber_AfterUpdate()
    ' Use Nz to avoid runtime error when myNumber is NULL
    Me!RomanNumber = RomanNumeral(Nz(Me!myNumber, 0))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andre. It works a treat in as much as it shows the Roman numerals on the Form but it does not save them into the field of the database.